# How to support drag&drop with full calendar on ipad

Tags: visualforce, calendar, ipad

We are integrating fullcalendar plugin with sf visualforce page. Needless to say, full calendar is very powerful and everything worked well. Then we want to show this page in salesforce1 of ipad, everything is fine but event drag&drop can't work! How to solve this issue? Full calendar can't support drag&drop on ipad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my guess is right you are trying to use this jquery plugin

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Right? I never used this specific plugin but I assume its draganddrop is based on jquerys draggable()

Usually jquerys draggable wont work on ipad. However i was able to use this to get draganddrop working on ios devices
http://touchpunch.furf.com/

I cant provide you a complete patch for fullcalendar but you have good chances to figure it out. Most likely it has nothing at all to do with salesforce1 but is a pure jquery issue.

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks, Uwe! I refered to jQuery UI Touch Punch script in my page, then put below code in the eventRender function of full calendar:
$(element).draggable();
It works!